# A way to trace streets from an android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, openstreetmap

I'm developing a game that requires objects to follow streets on screen. What I need is a way for the user to pick their location and have the app get map data for that location so game can trace the streets.

I tried using the Google Maps Static API to trace pixels from the bitmap, but converting a bitmap was an incredible processor hog. I looked at OpenStreetMap, but I couldn't find a way to download the xml map data programmatically from within the app and it downloads in .osm format.

Any suggestions? Thank You

Answer (score 0):

OpenStreetMap offers a variety of [APIs](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Databases_and_data_access_APIs) which you can use to download specific parts of the planet by specifying a bounding box (*bbox*). You most probably want to use the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) as it currently seems to be the fastest and most feature-rich API. It also supports different output formats.